# How to get installed exe file system path after scheduling in windows scheduler?

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, exe, scheduler

I have written in my console application a line `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("ApplicationSubDirectory")` to get application directory file system path.

I build this application and installed exe in my system. exe has been installed in `c://ProgramFiles/AppFolder/` directory. When I execute exe then I got valid path like `c://ProgramFiles/AppFolder/ApplicationSubDirectory`.

But when i scheduled this exe to run dailly basis in windows scheduler. Then I am getting wrong path. This returns me path of directory where windows scheduler is installed like `c://Windows/System32/ApplicationSubDirectory`. This is wrong path.

Please help me how i get valid path after scheduling exe too.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your console application is started by the Task Scheduler. To obtain the actual path add the following code to your application

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler sets the current directory to the path mentioned above.
`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("ApplicationSubDirectory")` uses the current directory.

You could try [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your support PrinceCharles.